# os x-lion: Programmatically launch my app when built-in iCal mac app is launched?

Tags: osx-lion

I have an Mac application developed, i am newbie to mac dev, but well known on iOS development. My app has an Login UI, so i may not be able to run in background i guess, and i don't know even how to run my Mac app in the background. I want to launch my application whenever iCal app is launched on the Mac system. Is it possible to programmatically launch an app when built-in iCal app is launched?

Comment: Anybody please? I need your help urgently...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A daemon can be launched automatically in login UI, to detect iCal launch. For daemon stuff, I prefer to redirect you to this very complete [Apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW1-SW1).

For detecting program launch, see the `NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotification` of `NSNotificationCenter`; you have to register for this notification in the notification center.

Then on detecting iCal launch, the daemon would launch your application.

Comment: Hi Charles, I registered for this event. But, I want to launch my app automatically when iCal is launched. How to do that using NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotification? Could you give me more info?

Comment: what is your trouble, it that you don't know how to execute code on NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotification? or is it that you don't know how to launch an app?

Comment: Thank you. I'll check right now and update. I'm new to creating daemon stuff and how it launched my app. I'm reading the Apple doc you shared.

Comment: I created launcd.plist file in my Mac app, and added Label, KeepAlive, ProgramArguments like this <key>ProgramArguments</key>
 <array>
  <string>exampled</string>
 </array>
 <key>KeepAlive</key>
 <true/>
 <key>ServiceIPC</key>
 <true/>
 <key>Label</key>
 <string>com.dalabs.myapp</string> I don't know what next i should do to achieve my requirement

Comment: Reading at the docs, i am seeing 'Agents" is the best for my purpose, since it allows also to have GUI and background process, when daemon doesn't. Any suggestions please?

Comment: In case you run it as an Agent note it won't be launched before user login, but maybe that's what you want... If you run it as a daemon it won't have a GUI but it will only launch your app so it doesn't need a GUI. I don't know what's best, maybe it's a good fit for another question :) However in [design article](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/DesigningDaemons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW4-BBCBHBFB) it says that launch agent shouldn't present UI

Comment: Actually, this is what my app should do. 1. Whenever iCal is launched, launch my app too with an Login UI. User should launch it for further synchronous process. 'Logout' UI is also provided 2. Then onwards my app should always run in the background and do sync. 3. If user quits my app, then alert the user that, my app will be relaunched again when again iCal is launched. Please advise which one should be correct way of doing?

Comment: that's beyond my knowledge, sorry, you should better ask for another question

Comment: Hi Charles, i think, 'Agents' is the one suitable for me, because it allows to have limited UI and also runs in the background process as per the doc says here-> http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2083/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003794

Comment: Hi Charles, Do you know, how my app can be launched as soon as iCal is launched?

Comment: I already told you that the point you raised (agent vs daemon) is beyond my knowledge, and can make another post.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you. I already made the Agent, its just adding "Application is agent (UIElement)" in plist. It worked too. I am looking into now how i can launch my app as soon as iCal is launched. Thank you for your support though!

Comment: Doesn't my answer deal with this?